# How to solve Shoelace sl-input style issues when used in Svelte app

Tags: svelte, shoelace

I have an issue with using Shoelace `sl-input` component with a Svelte application. When the component first loads, ie on refresh the browser, the element appears correctly styled for a moment, and then a short moment after, the padding is removed from the input. It remains this way until the bundler (vite) updates the content due to a change in the components code.

My svelte layout:

```html
<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.1.0/dist/themes/light.css" />
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.1.0/dist/shoelace.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<slot />
```

and my component:

```html
<script>
  import Debug from '@/develop/components/Debug.svelte'

  let data = {
    label: 'Mrs Smith',
    email: 'mrs.smith@gmail.com',
    phone: '(760) 697-2540'
  }
  
  function onChange (event) {
    const field = event.target.getAttribute('field')
    const value = event.target.value
    // todo: sanitize, validate
    data[field] = value
  }
</script>

<form method='' actions='' style='--d:grid; --gg:1rem;'>
  <sl-input label='Name' field='label' value={data.label} on:sl-change={onChange}></sl-input>
  <sl-input label='Email' field='email' value={data.email} on:sl-change={onChange}></sl-input>
  <sl-input label='Phone' field='phone' value={data.phone} on:sl-change={onChange}></sl-input>
</form>

<Debug data={data} />
```

I cannot understand why the styling starts out correct, with padding on the input, then momentarily loses that padding, only to return when VITE refreshes content on change.

Comment: PS- adding the following. There are no other css files or styling libraries imported anywhere in the project and the behavior I've described is not seen in the following codepen, leading me to believe its either Svelte or Vite, or ... ? https://codepen.io/tremendusapps/pen/VwGavjN